# IIS Rewrite pattern matching exact URL

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I've got IIS7.5 running, and I'm trying to match an explicit URL. The following code does not work.

```
 <rule name="presid" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="http://www.example.com/presid" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.net/presid" />
  </rule>
```

I've also tried escaping the periods:

```
http://www\.example\.com/presid
```

but that doesn't seem to work either. How do I match a specific full URL using IIS7.5?

This works, but does not do exactly what I'm after: (.*)/presid, but I have images that break:

http://example.com/images/presid/eee.jpg

I don't want that image to get redirected.

Comment: REQUEST_URI does not contain the hostname.

use this instead:

<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/presid$" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />

Answer (score 7, accepted):

REQUEST_URI does not contain the hostname.

use this instead:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/presid$" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
```

Answer (score 3):

When I needed to match an exact full URL, I have used 2 conditions, one for the host and one for the rest, such as:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.yourdomain.com" />
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="pages/yourpage.aspx" />
```